# definition of block diagonal operator on a hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I 'm stuck with the definition of block diagonal operators on hilbert spaces.

Def.: A bounded linear operator $T$ on a hilbert space $H$ is called block diagonal if there exists an increasing sequence of finite rank projections $P_1\le P_2\le P_2 ...$, such that $\| [T,P_n]\|=\|TP_n-P_nT\|=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\|P_nx-Id_Hx\|_H\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

With "block diagonal operator" I associate linear operators with block diagonal matrices on finite dimensional vector spaces. But I don't see the connection with the definition above, can you explain me this? I only know that for $H$ exists a (maybe uncountable) (Hamel-)basis $\{u_j\}_{j\in J}$. In the countable case you can talk about "infinite dimensional matrices".

Answer (score 1):

Let's show, then, that a block-diagonal matrix fits this definition.  Consider an operator $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ given by
$$
T = \pmatrix{A_1\\& A_2 \\ && \ddots \\ &&& A_m}
$$
where $A_i$ is an $n_i \times n_i$ matrix (so, of course, $\sum_i n_i = n$).

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis vectors of $\Bbb R^n$.  Define
$$
P_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j e_j \right) = \sum_{j=1}^{n_1 + \cdots + n_i} a_j e_j \qquad i = 1,\dots,k-1
$$
and define $P_i = \operatorname{id} = I_{n}$ for $i \geq k$.
Of course, each $P_i$ is a projection operator.  Furthermore, we have
$$
P_i = \pmatrix{I_{n_1}\\&\ddots\\ &&I_{n_i}\\ &&&0 \\ &&&& \ddots \\ &&&&& 0}
$$
so clearly $[T,P_i] = 0$ for every $i$. I think you'll also find that the second condition clearly holds.

Comment: I don't think you'll have any trouble extending this construction to an *infinite block diagonal matrix*, but if you do, or if you'd like a similar explanation, let me know.

Comment: Note that another technically correct demonstration that $T$ is block diagonal occurs if we take $P_i = I_n$ for *every* $i$, since $T$ is itself a block of finite size.  However, I think that this "maximal chain" of $P_n$ illustrates the point more clearly.